# Python: how to seperate a list to several list based on empty string?

Tags: python, list

I'm working a on a list like this, `a = ['a','b','','','c','d']`, the real list is including thousands of data entries. Is there a fancy way to make the list `a` as `[['a','b'],['c','d]]` because the data is really huge?

Comment: What should the output look like if there was a single (or an odd number) of blank strings in a row?

Comment: if there is a single blank string like a = ['a','','b','','','c','d'], I want [['a','','b'],['c','d]] Thank you so much

Comment: Now I have to ask about what to do for 3 (or more) blank strings in  a row, since your single blank example doesn't really explain enough.

Comment: What should:['a','b','','c','d'] look like?  What about: ['a','','','',b','','c','d']?  Maybe you can add examples, and explain better exactly what to do with blanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.groupby` for this. You basically group by consecutive empty strings, or consecutive non-empty strings. Then keep all groups that were grouped by `True` from the lambda in a list comprehension.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby

>>> [list(i[1]) for i in groupby(a, lambda i: i != '') if i[0]]
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

For another example

```
>>> b = ['a','b','','','c','d', '', 'e', 'f', 'g', '', '', 'h']
>>> [list(i[1]) for i in groupby(b, lambda i: i != '') if i[0]]
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['h']]
```

Comment: In this case, you could use `bool` instead of `lambda i: i != ''`, in the same way you'd normally write `if i:` instead of `if i != '':`. I'm not sure whether that would be more readable or less in this case—it makes it less explicit that you're dealing with strings, but it also cuts a lot of irrelevant boilerplate out of the expression, so… I guess just try it both ways and see which seems more readable to you.

Comment: Also, I think it might be more readable as `[list(g) for k, g in groupby(…)]`, but that's really nitpicky, so feel free to ignore it.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! But I don't want it separate when there is only one blank string.  like a = ['a','','b','','','c','d'], what I expect is [['a','','b'],['c','d]].